# Toggle dialog not working in jQuery. How to show animation dialog in button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a button which succesfully toggles many elements on the page, but they are all below the height of the starting page, leading to the user not clearly getting feedback that they've succesfully toggled. I want to use a jQuery dialog which toggles open when I succesfully toggle those other elements open.

**So I did this (jQuery):**

```
 window.onload = function () {
    $("#toggleAllSSSP").click(function () {
      $(".SSSP").toggle('fast');
      $( "#toggleSuccess" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
          effect: "blind",
          duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
          effect: "explode",
          duration: 1000
        }
      });
      $( "#toggleSuccess" ).dialog( "open" );
    }); 
};
```

[With inspiration from this page.](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated)

**And here's the HTML**

```
<button id="toggleAllSSSP">Show 4 levels of principles Principles (Default=3)</button>
<div id="toggleSuccess" title="Toggle success">
    <p>You're now displaying 4 levels of Principles!</p>
</div>
```

I tried adding css to `#toggleSuccess` with the result of an element appearing as normal in the flow of the DOM. I know I could use window.alert but would prefer this solution, thanks.

Comment: Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/989071/

Answer (score 1):

Please initialize your dialog separately (not inside "click" event handler). Also please be sure you've included jquery and jquery.ui to your scripts (+ jquery.ui.css). Hope it helps.

```js
$("#toggleAllSSSP").click(function () {
  $(".SSSP").toggle('fast'); 
  $("#toggleSuccess").dialog( "open" );
}); 
    
$("#toggleSuccess").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  show: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 1000
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "explode",
    duration: 1000
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<button id="toggleAllSSSP">Show 4 levels of principles Principles (Default=3)</button>
<div id="toggleSuccess" title="Toggle success">
  <p>You're now displaying 4 levels of Principles!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Linked all like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../stylesheets/IntPrinCSS/BoostOdds.css">
<script src="/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../javascripts/toggleP.js"></script>` But it's still not working. I changed the jQuery code too, without success, thanks for the help.

Comment: Might there be a problem with the jquery ui css `p { display:block; }` ?

Comment: At this point, the toggle for other elements stopped working too. :| .

Comment: @Ronnlidd, I don’t know the full structure of your code. Not sure how to help you with all of your toggle elements. I’ve just tried to answer  your main question.

Comment: Yeah, I see, I have not idea why it doesn't work, seems to me like it should... Thanks though.

Comment: @Ronnlidd, may be it helps to check how each toggle element was initialized and if it triggers to be shown correctly.

Comment: Thanks, found another solution: Making the dialog box show on the actual toggle click as a paragraph, it manipulates the DOM but that's fine in my case.